# 403 Forbidden when accessing host OS's localhost on guest VM

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, virtualbox, http-status-code-403

I am getting 403 Forbidden error when I try to access my host OS's localhost on my guest vm running Windows 8.1 on VirtualBox. To access my host's `localhost/myPage`, I am running `10.0.2.2/myPage` on my guest. The error code shown to me is:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /myPage on this server.

Console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Another site I am testing locally (on port 3000) returned a blank screen with this in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

For some reason however, I can see the site's icon in the browser tab with Internet Explorer (not possible with Chrome).

If it helps, I was also able to access my site (only tested the port 3000 one, `'10.0.2.2:3000/myPage'`) once last week, however when I tried again today, I received this error. I have no memory of modifying anything that might've affected this issue, although I might've done something by accident. Is there a chance that I am just accessing my host's sites incorrectly?

Or would this be an issue with my apache settings?

I can ping my host `10.0.2.2` on my guest OS with no errors. I can also access both of my sites locally on my host OS with no issues.

Host OS: OS X 10.11.6
Guest OS: Win 7, 8.1 (both from Microsoft's [developer site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. For my machine, the network adapter had to be set as `NAT Network` and not the default `NAT` that the Windows image from Microsoft came with.

VirtualBox settings:

[image]

Hope this is useful for anyone else running into this problem.

Comment: after that I lost my internet on VB